# Using snakemake checkpoint + aggregate to get an unknown number of IDs from the internet

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

Here is a pared down example of what I am trying to do:

```
rule all:
    input: "results.txt"

rule find_data:
    output: "work_dir/data.txt"
    run:
        # pretend this retrives IDs
        with open(output[0], 'w') as fh:
            for i in map(str, range(5)):
                print(i, file=fh)

checkpoint download_data:
    input: "work_dir/data.txt"
    output: directory("work_dir/{sample_id}")
    run:
        with open(input[0], 'r') as fh:
            for l in fh:
                l = l.rstrip()
                # pretend this downloads data
                shell("touch work_dir/{}".format(l))


def aggregate_signatures(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.download_data.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand("work_dir/{sample_id}", sample_id=checkpoint_output.sample_id)

rule make_database:
    input: aggregate_signatures
    output: "results.txt"
    shell:
         "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Which leads to the error

```
InputFunctionException in line 40 of /Users/ian.fiddes/test_sourmash/sourmash/Snakefile:
WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values for sample_id
Wildcards:
```

I am not sure how the code above functionally differs from the example in the Data Dependent Conditional Execution section of the snakemake manual.

The idea here is to download some unknown number of IDs from the internet, then have jobs that take one ID per job and go download some data, then have intermediate steps that process those data before aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You are close!

The rule that should let snakemake re-evaluate the DAG is not `download_data`, but it is `find_data`. Since after you found the data you want to check which data you have. So making `find_data` a checkpoint, and changing the corresponding line in `aggregate_signatures` is all you have to do:

```
checkpoint_output = checkpoints.find_data.get(**wildcards).output[0]
```